# Question about the usage of the comma in sentence; before adverb

Tags: sentence-structure

There is the example of sentence below.

she walked slowly down the road, evidently in pain.

As you can see, there is the independent Clause after that, and "comma" is put in sentence which
consists the adverb and adjective phrase;this isn't a independent clause.

I just want to know why the "comma" is put in this sentence.

I'd like to listen to your clear explanation.

Comment: When you put something is quotes, it means that you're talking about the word itself, not what it refers to. But you're talking about an actual comma, not the word "comma", so it shouldn't be in quotes. And you say "sentence below", but the example isn't actually below.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fix my question!!

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the sentence without the comma:

```
She walked slowly down the road evidently in pain.
```

It's confusing because `evidently` appears to be modifying `road`, since it follows `road` immediately.

If we separate the two thoughts into their own sentences:

```
She walked slowly down the road. Evidently she was in pain.
```

This is, at least, clear; in terms of readability, the two sentences are a bit choppy, and it might read more easily and be considered to 'flow' better if they were combined.

```
She walked slowly down the road, evidently in pain.
```

The two thoughts fit together, the slowness of the walking explained by the evident pain.

I would regard this as a dependent clause; I don't know the exact grammatical structure someone would fit it to, but the comma is necessary and the sentence reads better than its two-sentence equivalent. The version without the comma reads badly and is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand it easily, Can I, however, change sentence into another form? That is, "She walked slowly down the road, evidently being in pain."

Comment: I *think* that's grammatically correct, but it sure doesn't sound right.

Comment: I hit on an idea. I suggest another tranformation of that sentence if possible. That is, She walked slowly down the road, which was evidently in pain.

Comment: The 'which' unfortunately refers to the most recent noun, which is "road". Probably not what you meant.